# Single WCF .svc, multiple clients connecting

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have created a WCF Service with multiple Interfaces. This serves multiple users at one time.

Do I need to alter anything in the ServiceContract or ServiceBehaviour to make sure that there's no "crossing" over between two clients?

The ServiceContract is left blank, however the ServiceBehaviour in my .svc is like so:

```
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall, AutomaticSessionShutdown:=True,
             ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults:=True)>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Validation:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IdentityModel.Selectors
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Security
Imports System.Threading
Imports DVPWCFService.Modules

Namespace Classes.Admin

    Public Class Validation
        Inherits UserNamePasswordValidator

        Private _dbUsername As String
        Private _dbPassword As SecureString

        Public Overrides Sub Validate(userName As String, password As String)
            Try
                _dbUsername = userName
                _dbPassword = ConvertToSecureString(password)
                DbUsername = userName
                DbPassword = ConvertToSecureString(password)

                Dim dummyConnectionForValidation As SqlConnection = LogInTry("A real server name")

                dummyConnectionForValidation.Close()
                dummyConnectionForValidation.Dispose()

            Catch ex As Exception

                If ex.GetType Is GetType(SqlException) Then
                    DVPEventLog.WriteEntry("Authentication has failed for user: '" + userName + "'", EventLogEntryType.Warning)
                Else
                    DVPEventLog.WriteEntry("Error: " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Stack Trace: " & ex.StackTrace & Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine & "Method Name: " & MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, EventLogEntryType.Error, EventLogEntryType.Error)
                End If

                Thread.Sleep(5000)

                Throw New FaultException("Log in failed.")
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Function LogInTry(serverName As String) As SqlConnection
            LogInTry = New SqlConnection
            LogInTry.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & serverName & ";Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
            LogInTry.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = True
            LogInTry.Credential = New SqlCredential(_dbUsername, _dbPassword)
            LogInTry.Open()
        End Function

        Private Function ConvertToSecureString(convertee As String) As SecureString

            ConvertToSecureString = New SecureString()

            For Each stringCharacter In convertee.ToCharArray()
                ConvertToSecureString.AppendChar(stringCharacter)
            Next

            ConvertToSecureString.MakeReadOnly()

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Web Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>

      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SSL Binding" openTimeout="00:00:20" receiveTimeout="08:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="TripleDesSha256Rsa15" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <services>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="Custom Validation Service Behavior" name="DVPWCFService.DVP">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSL Binding"
          name="IComponent" contract="DVPWCFService.Interfaces.IComponent" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSL Binding"
          name="IProgramme" contract="DVPWCFService.Interfaces.IProgramme" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSL Binding"
          name="IVehicle" contract="DVPWCFService.Interfaces.IVehicle" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSL Binding"
          name="IMiscellaneous" contract="DVPWCFService.Interfaces.IMiscellaneous" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="metadata"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSL Binding"
          name="IReservation" contract="DVPWCFService.Interfaces.IReservation" />
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="Custom Validation Service Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"
            includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="blahblahblah"
              x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
              customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="DVPWCFService.Classes.Admin.Validation, DVPWCFService"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
          <dataContractSerializer />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10" maxConcurrentSessions="10" maxConcurrentInstances="1" />
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: That configuration, if bound correctly to the service, looks like it will do what you want it to do - one instance per client connection.

Comment: I set a username variable on the Override Sub Authenticate. This is fine when a single user is using it, however when another logs in, it overwrites it for some reason... @RossBush

Comment: @Connor_smaith14 - I bet you have your session state to allow or require. Do you want to prohibit session state in your service?

Comment: @RossBush Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I believe so, each user connecting to the WCF will have a different username and password, I will use these to log in to a database to retrieve data etc.

Comment: That is because the username is per client. Could you post your authentication code and expected behavior?

Comment: @RossBush Added. I thought that it would Validate on each call, therefore keeping the username the same one on each call. Maybe I don't understand it as well as I thought.

Comment: @RossBush I also added my web config. Still can't sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after several hours of digging, to force it to authenticate on each call and therefore not intervene with other contexts, I put this in the binding:

```
<message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
 algorithmSuite="TripleDesSha256Rsa15" 
 establishSecurityContext="false" />
```

The important bit being **establishSecurityContext="false"**, the default for this is true so it remembers the last established log in, when you set it to false, it re-authenticates on each call. For this to be efficient, you'll need your authentication code to be slick.